# Slide view while touching button - IOS

Tags: ios5

I'm trying to implement a view that includes social buttons.In normal state, it will be partially hide and only the "Opciones" button and the upper line is shown.  This view will be shown when user touches button "Opciones" (touch gesture), then it will unhide and be shown using sliding effect until the final position that is included in the attached image.

[image]

I'm wondering which kind of control and animation I have to use.

Many thanks.